# How to draw square box with specific dimensions at left upper corner?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to draw a 2 cm x 2 cm square box in the left upper corner in Pillow on an existing image, but here I am struggling to draw a square box on a blank canvas itself. My code is as follows:

```
def drawrect(drawcontext, xy, outline=None, width=0):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = xy
    print(drawcontext)
    print(xy)
    points = (x1, y1), (x2, y1), (x2, y2), (x1, y2), (x1, y1)
    print(points)
    drawcontext.line(points, fill=outline, width=width)

# example
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
im = Image.new("RGB", (150, 150), color="white")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

drawrect(draw, [(5, 5), (100, 100)], outline="red", width=5)

im.show()
```

How to draw a rectangle/square with specific dimensions in cms in the left upper corner of a canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Partially problem is solved much simpler code written

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw as D
i=Image.open("mirror.jpg")
draw=D.Draw(i)
draw.rectangle([(30,30),(100,100)],fill=(255,0,0), outline="white",width=2)
i.show()
```

But do not know how to draw 2cm x 2cm box. Pl help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a resolution, and convert your cm measures to proper pixels measures. When saving, you need to specify the resolution again. Let's see this example:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Resolution
dpi = 300


# Convert cm measure to pixels measure w.r.t. resolution.
def cm_to_px(cm):
    return int(cm / 2.54 * dpi)


# Image width and height in cm
w, h = (7, 5)

# Create empty image
image = Image.new('RGB', (cm_to_px(w), cm_to_px(h)), color='#FFFFFF')

# Rectangle width and height in cm
(wr, hr) = (3, 2)

# Draw rectangle
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle([(10, 10), (cm_to_px(wr), cm_to_px(hr))], outline='#FF0000', width=5)

# Save image
image.save('output.png', dpi=(dpi, dpi))
```

The goal is to get a 7 cm x 5 cm white image with a 3 cm x 2 cm red outlined box.

The result looks like this:

[image: Output]

When opening that image – in GIMP for example – I get the information, that the image has measures 7 cm x 5 cm with a resolution of 300 dpi. So, exactly what we wanted.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```